# Cannot read property "cache' of client.users

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So in my discord bot,I want to find out a info of a member by using their id - like !userinfo 2355846847 or smth- like that !

But whenever I use client.users.cache.get(arguments[0] , it returns me an error saying cannot read property cache of undefined.

```
callback :async (message,arguments,client,text) => {
  

message.channel.startTyping(2)
var target =  message.mentions.users.first() || client.users.fetch(arguments[0]) || message.author
```

When I tried to console log client.users, it always return undefined although logging only client works fine as normal gives me info about my bot.

```
const client =new Discord.Client()
```

This is how I define my client! Does anybody know what is causing this particular case?

Comment: Can you show how you call the `callback(...)` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re outside of the file where you initiate your client, you can get access to the client via `message.client` (e.g. `await message.client.users.fetch(arguments[0])`) You can still do it the way you have so far if you make sure the parameters in your callback are in the correct order and all correctly defined, but getting the client from the message object bypasses that issue.